# Can we use bash here document to run perl script?

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I run the below perl script as a bash here document. My intention is that a variable is read from STDIN, then the arithmetic calculation is done and then printed.

However, the program is finished at once without waiting for input from STDIN.

A warning "Use of uninitialized value $input in multiplication (*) at - line 6."  is printed out before the 2 strings in line 4 and line 6 are printed. Note that no prompt exists to read the STDIN.

Why would this happen?
I would like to combine the here document in bash and the perl script, so the perl script with very few lines can be run in the shell without bothering to write a script file. 
(I know perl -e option is an alternative, but I just wonder why my method doesn't work.)

```
bash-4.1$ bash
bash-4.1$ perl <<'EOF'
> use strict;
> use warnings;
> my $input;
> print "Please enter a number:";
> $input=<STDIN>;
> print 2+2*3.141592654*$input."\n";
> EOF
Use of uninitialized value $input in multiplication (*) at - line 6.
Please enter a number:2
bash-4.1$
```